# 4" 800х480 dimens.xml file location issue

Tags: android, android-layout

need to separate dimensions for an old device 4" 800х480 and the rest, where should I put dimens.xml file?

App is designed for normal phones (full HD res ~5") but need to support this exact old sizes too.

I used values-sw320dp but all devices are getting dimensions from there.

Comment: First do not move the default file from dimens. If you need additional files you just create them for ex if you need sw320dp dimens you create another file in sw320dp folder android will check the bigger buckets first if the device fits into the 720dp bucket the system will try to find the resource inside sw720dp if the resource is not there then it checks the next lower bucket until it reaches the default file and it uses that. i'm sure there are some more things involved but this is basically how it works.

Comment: Also you don't need to duplicate all the values in all the folder. Lets say valueX changes when 320dp then 320dp will contain just the valueX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, so I keep using dimens.xml foreach screen size like so:

```
values-mdpi/dimnes.xml
values-hdpi/dimnes.xml
values-xhdpi/dimnes.xml
values-xxhdpi/dimnes.xml
values-xxxhdpi/dimnes.xml
```